# Does setting meta tags in Javascript work without server side rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, meta

I am developing a single page application and each page should have different open graph meta tags.

It seems that tools like `react-helmet` just use Javascript functions like `element.setAttribute` to update the meta tags as you transition between pages.

My question is: does this work without server side rendering? Because in this case you would have a "default" set of meta tags and then when the page is loaded the client-side routing would determine what page you were actually on and then the Javascript would set the proper meta tags in the `onPageLoad` handler.

That is, if you inspect the source for the page, the meta tags would be just the default, but if some crawler instead waited for the page to load and then inspected the new meta tags, they would see the proper values.

I don't use server side rendering. Is it a waste of time to use something like react-helmet without server side rendering? If I link my page on Slack or Discord will it simply inspect the source to determine the meta tags or does it wait for the page to load and then grab the newer meta tags that were set via Javascript?

I figured I'd ask rather than test first because developing this functionality and pushing to production is a decent amount of work if this isn't even supported and someone already knows that.

Comment: It seems like they do: [google docs: JavaScript SEO Basics](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics).

Comment: So, Google seems smart enough to wait for Javascript to run before grabbing things like meta tags, but is this sort of plan reliable? Will general chat applications (Slack, Discord, etc.) also wait for the Javascript to run before grabbing meta tags like `og:image`, or will links to my site look "blank" when linked to in these applications?

Comment: True, for other crawlers, you'll probably need some sort of server-side rendering.  You can use [Canonical URLs](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization): hardcode your index.html to have `<link rel.../>` to some small server side script that only generates the `og:` tags you want, and some JS to redirect for users who end up on that page.  Can't think of anything better without fully server-side scripting.

Comment: See the [tag:seo] tag. Questions asking how search engines will interact with certain code are off-topic here.

Comment: I am not asking how search engines will interact with certain code. I'm entirely concerned with whether or not `og` meta tags work with conforming clients when they are rendered client-side.

Comment: To test you could post the link on Facebook to see which open graph tags are seen

Comment: Yes I'm aware that I could develop the feature, push it to prod, and then see for myself, but it seems wasteful for everyone to have to do that. I'd prefer if there was a canonical answer on stackoverflow that people could refer to rather than everyone having to repeat the same test for themselves.

Comment: I think it's a fine question.  Btw, why not just check someone's website that already does this?  ([facebook source](https://www.facebook.com/) (view-source, no og tags)  And it seems like the og tags are picked up by [linkedin-sharer](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F).

Comment: Facebook's page source seems to have og tags?

Comment: I don't see them in the source code, which appears obfuscated?  (Facebook is a React app.)  Do a text search on "og:", no results.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing http://prerender.io/ - this will detect crawlers, cache the appropriate sites and serve the appropriate sites.